# Handle non-JSON data in @ngrx/effects

Tags: ngrx-effects, angular4-httpclient

I don't know how to handle the non-JSON data in @ngrx/effects

I want to parse the text not JSON

```js
//effects
@Effect() getNonJsonData = () => this.actions
        .ofType<GetNonJsonAction>(GET_NON_JSON_DATA)
        .switchMap(() => this.api
            .getNonJsonData()
            .map(getNonJsonDataFulfilled)
            .catch(error => Observable.of(getNonJsonDataRejected(error)))
        )
//api
getNonJsonData(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>('my_http_url');// It returns 'ACCESS' or 'NON_ACCESS' string not return JSON
}
```

It always go to the `getNonJsonDataRejected` action, its not going to `getNonJsonDataFulfilled` action.

I'm getting this error message
`"Http failure during parsing, name:"HttpErrorResponse"`

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad`

Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i find out the answer, we need to add the `{responseType: 'text'}` in the http api call, so the code is,

```
getNonJsonData(): Observable<string> {
   return this.http.get('my_http_url', {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

ref: https://blog.hackages.io/angular-http-httpclient-same-but-different-86a50bbcc450